# how to update the cursor on the first position?

Tags: android, sqlite

When I delete data from my database, the cursor remains on next position.
I need to update the cursor on the first position after delete the all data.
Give me some hint or code.
Thank you!

Comment: by using this line of code: `cursor.moveToFirst();`. you can move cursor to first position. check if this help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using this line of code:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

you can move cursor to first position.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try: `cursor.moveToFirst()` method?